# How will I extend my speaker wire?

Tags: speakers

The wire is too short for me, and I want to extend it...

I'm thinking that the audio quality will lessen if I connect a different wire.

I don't know as well if where will I get or what wire will I use

[image]

Comment: Speaker wire quality has far less to do with final sound quality than you'd think. If you use anything at all reasonably thick, and properly insulated, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can [twist together a string of coat hangers](http://www.zdnet.com/article/coat-hanger-wire-is-just-as-good-as-a-high-quality-speaker-cable/) and I'd bet you wouldn't notice the sound quality difference.

> After 5 tests, none could determine which was the Monster 1000 cable or the coat hanger wire. Further, when music was played through the coat hanger wire, we were asked if what we heard sounded good to us. All agreed that what was heard sounded excellent, however, when A-B tests occurred, it was impossible to determine which sounded best the majority of the time and which wire was in use.

Solder, crimp, or twist on a length of wire equal to or larger than the existing wire and be happy.

Comment: +1 for the coathangers reference. I wouldn't recommend twisting them together, some outdoor speakers at my house stopped working, and I found that over time, the tape loosened and the weight of the wire pulled apart the (unsupported) twisted connection. Soldering or a crimp connector would be much better since that gives a strong physical connection. Though I'm sure it makes no difference in sound quality.

Comment: Sure. I meant wire nuts. Electrical tape is a sure fail.

Comment: Solder and shrink tube FTW if it's outdoors.

Comment: You'll want to solder the coat hangers.  I recommend SilverGold CH audiophile-grade solder specifically made for coat hanger speaker connections.